# How to select date in selenium Webdriver from ajax calendarextender using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
IWebElement date = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_masterContentPlaceHolder_ImgBtnModifiedStart"));
IList<IWebElement> row = date.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
IList<IWebElement> col = date.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

for (IWebElement cell: col)
{
    if (cell.Equals("13"))
    {
        cell.FindElement(By.LinkText("13")).Click();
    }
}


Error Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement occured at for loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is worked for me :)

IWebElement date = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_masterContentPlaceHolder_CalendarExtender3_daysBody"));

```
        IList<IWebElement> row = date.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        IList<IWebElement> col = date.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

        foreach (IWebElement cell in col)
        {
            if (cell.Text.Equals("13"))  
            {
                cell.Click();
                break;
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
if (cell.Equals("13"))
```

You want to access the `Text` property of the `IWebElement`...

```
if (cell.Text.Equals("13")) .....
```